# Closed-source alternative to Quartz.NET

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler

This may seem like an odd question, but I need to find a closed-source alternative to Quartz.NET. I have been using quartz in a windows service application I am writing, and recently discovered that my employer will not allow me to use open-source controls in my project (funny, since there is plenty of UNIX stuff running here as well...sheesh).

Anyone have any suggestions on a control that I can use? Thanks!

Comment: Is it because of licensing issues?

Comment: I don't think that Unix is necessarily open source.

Comment: Not really sure what their issue is...it just came down that I shouldn't use it unless I absolutely have to...

Comment: True about the Unix...sorry, I just felt a little b*tchy, I take back that statement.

Comment: Don't worry, you aren't alone--there is a suprising amount of companies with rules like that.

Comment: Quartz.NET is released under the Apache license, which basically only demands that you carry on the copyright and state that you used it. So maybe talk to your employer about what his concerns are.

Comment: It might be a little more helpful to know what the objection is.  Is it the license? Liability? Obscurity? Quality? Ignorance?

Comment: Probably mostly ignorance, but lets just say that I work for the gov't, so I would believe the concern would be security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears as though I have talked the superiors into allowing me to use Quartz (as long as I don't mention that I am using it, hehe). Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: If your work is to be distributed, make sure that you comply with Apache License section 4.4. If there are notices you are required to preserve, be sure to do so. If it's purely in-house development, then this doesn't matter.

Comment: it is in fact in house...i had already considered the license and reviewed it to be sure, but no distribution will be taking place!

Answer (score 3):

Keeping in mind that closed source usually means you have to pay, here is a solution that might fit your needs:

1. [PortSight Task Scheduler for .NET](http://www.portsight.com/Products.aspx?AliasPath=Products/Task%20Scheduler/Task%20Scheduler&CultureAlias=en-US)

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Tidal](http://www.tidalsoftware.com/products/schedulingforPlatforms.aspx) which is now part of Cisco.

Comment: Tidal and PortSight seem ok, but they are more a replacement for the Windows Task Scheduler. I need something that can run a method in my code at a specified interval, much like using a System.Threading.Timer (which is ultimately what I was trying to replace with Quartz).